# Expo calendar Alarm usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-calendar-api, expo

I’m trying to figure out how to use the alarms provided with the Expo Calendar.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Here's the alarm provided by Expo Calendar [Expo Alarm](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/calendar.html#alarm)

The events are being created fine but I want an alarm to trigger at a given time.

Is this possible?

Here's a reproducible Expo snack [Expo Calendar Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@hmadugula/expo-calendar)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The 'alarms' property is an array of Alarm objects
This object is defined in Calendar.js:

```
type Alarm = {
    absoluteDate?: string, //iOS
    relativeOffset?: string,
    structuredLocation?: {
        //iOS
        title?: string,
        proximity?: string, // Proximity
        radius?: number,
        coords?: {
        latitude?: number,
        longitude?: number,
        },
    },
    method?: string, //Method, Android
};
```

So if you want to set the alarm on a specific date, you could do:

```
alarms: [ { absoluteDate: "2019-05-05T12:00:00:000Z" } ]
```

Or if you wanted it to be 15 minutes before:

```
alarms: [ { relativeOffset: -15 } ]
```